# How to read Text Field value from another file through a Dialog?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, save, ini

I have two files in my package: **GUI.java** and **Dialog.java**

The GUI has two Text Fields and a Button. When I press that Button, the Dialog becomes visible. The Dialog has another button which saves the Text Fields' values to an .ini file. And here comes the problem, it doesn't save the updated values, but the ones that were there when the program first started.

After some searches on Google I found out that I need to use something called "Action Listener", but I just can't seem to get it right at all.

**GUI.java:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.ini4j.Wini;

public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public GUI(){
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        textField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        textField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        openDialog = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textField1.setText("1");

        textField2.setText("2");

        openDialog.setText("Open Dialog");
        openDialog.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                openDialogActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(openDialog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(textField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(textField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(openDialog)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void openDialogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
         Dialog dialog = new Dialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
         dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
             @Override
             public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                 dialog.setVisible(false);
             }
         });
         dialog.setVisible(true);
    }                                          

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    void save(int i){
        try {
            Wini ini = new Wini(new File("C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/Configs.ini"));
            int firstValue = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
            int secondValue = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());
            ini.put("Configuration " + i, "First Value", firstValue);
            ini.put("Configuration " + i, "Second Value", secondValue);
            ini.store();
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
    private javax.swing.JButton openDialog;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textField2;                   
}
```

**Dialog.java:**

```
public class Dialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    GUI GUI = new GUI();
    public Dialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        save = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        save.setText("Save");
        save.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                saveActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(save)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(save)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        GUI.save(1);
    }                                    

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private javax.swing.JButton save;                 
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *`catch (IOException ex) {}`* Don't ignore exceptions! They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Ok, I have added a whole working example. As for the exception catch, I don't really care about it, I put it there only because NetBeans forced me to.

Comment: `Dialog` shouldn't be creating a new instance of `GUI` but instead, the instance of `GUI` which creates should be passing it a reference

Comment: *"As for the exception catch, I don't really care about it,.."* Will you continue to not care about it, when the application fails for no apparent reason? The only time an exception should be ignored, is when it can justified by the programmer (best in a comment in the code). Can you justify that if an exception is thrown at that point, that it can be ignored?

Comment: That piece of code works just fine and has no reason not to. If the application does ever fail saving the values into the .ini file, then I know where the problem is coming from. Catch woudln't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dialog` should not be creating a new instance of `GUI`, there is no relationship between the instance which is been displayed on the screen and that which `Dialog` is using.

Instead, `GUI` should pass a reference of itself to `Dialog`

```
public class Dialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private GUI gui;

    public Dialog(GUI parent) {
        super(parent, true);
        this.gui = gui;
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        save = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        save.setText("Save");
        save.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                saveActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addContainerGap()
                                                        .addComponent(save)
                                                        .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addContainerGap()
                                                        .addComponent(save)
                                                        .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        gui.save(1);
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton save;
}
```

This is pretty basic Java and something you should be familiar with before embarking on something as complicated as GUI development. See [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for more details

And your `GUI` class might look something like...

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        textField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        textField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        openDialog = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textField1.setText("1");

        textField2.setText("2");

        openDialog.setText("Open Dialog");
        openDialog.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                openDialogActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addContainerGap()
                                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                        .addComponent(openDialog, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                        .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                                        .addComponent(textField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                                        .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addContainerGap()
                                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                                        .addComponent(textField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                        .addComponent(textField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                        .addComponent(openDialog)
                                                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void openDialogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    void save(int i) {
        // Code I can't execute
        // Also, don't ignore the exception, you should probably
        // rethrow it...
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton openDialog;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textField2;
}
```

Although, I'd argue that, if you want `GUI` to save the data, it should be inspecting the result from the dialog, rather the exposing itself to possible mis-treatment (`removeAll` anyone?).  In that case, I'd consider using a `JOptionPane` instead

See [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.

Also, the sooner you ditch the form editor, the better you will become

> I will look forward and see if I can manage to make it work through JOptionPane

```
private void openDialogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this, "Do you wish to save", "Save", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
    if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        save(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I see how you linked GUI and Dialog to each other, but it gives me this error once I try to save the values: **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException**. I will look forward and see if I can manage to make it work through JOptionPane.

Comment: Actually, nevermind about JOptionPane. Its interface is way too hard to customize. So, any idea why your code doesn't work?

Comment: *"Its interface is way too hard to customize"* - Seriously, you want to display a "save" message and a "ok" button ... the update examples fix the NPE and demonstrate a more rich dialog prompt ... IMHO

Comment: Actually, I wanted it to look [like this.](https://i.imgur.com/PUvg7qd.png) I couldn't find how to make it have 6 buttons, with each 3 of them being in separated panels, so that's why I said it's too hard. I guess I'll make two separate Dialogs, one for saving and one for loading. The design will be minimal but it will do. Thanks a lot! Btw the first example still crashes with the same error, not that it matters anymore, though.

Comment: Well you can kind of make it work, because the second parameter accepts an `Object` which can be a component